# excel vba: Numberformat for a list of Columns

Tags: excel, vba, format

is there a shorter way for using numberFormaton a list of columns?
e.g. I have

```
.Columns("C").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_)"
.Columns("F").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_)"
.Columns("G").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_)"
```

something like (which does not work)

```
 Range(.Columns(3), .Columns(6), .Columns(9)).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_)"
```

thanks for helping,
dukehh

Comment: Change `Range` to `Union`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like so, could work for you.

```
Dim r As Excel.Range

Set r = Union(ActiveSheet.Columns(1), ActiveSheet.Columns(3), ActiveSheet.Columns(5))
r.Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Nathan_Sav's (thankU) solution like so:

```
   Dim r As Excel.Range
   Set r = Union(.Columns(3), .Columns(6), .Columns(9))
   r.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_)"
```

Answer (score 0):

another option

```vb
Dim col
For Each col In Array("A", "B", "C")
    .Columns(col).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_)"
Next col
```

but union is much faster